# How to merge 2 pivot tables (with different filters) to built a pivot graph

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, pivot-table, dax

I have 2 pivot tables:

**Pivot Table 1 / Oriented bugs**

Filter on Defect Release (value is `Release 5`) and Defect Cycle (value is `Cycle 3`)

```
Team Bugs | Count of bugs
Team1     | 84
Team2     | 120
Team3     | 17
Team4     | 41
Team5     | 24
```

**Pivot Table 2 / Oriented test**

Filter on Test Release (value is `Release 5`) and Test Cycle (value is `Cycle 3`)

```
Test Team | Count of tests
Team1     | 250
Team2     | 10
Team5     | 62
```

I would like to create a pivot graph with 2 bar by team. The first one have to be the count bugs and the second one the count of tests. Is it possible to merge both pivot table and apply specific filters by columns?

Find below a graph generated with a static view. I need to reproduce it with a Pivotchart now ... But I'm blocked due to headers and filters which are not based on same columns (even if values are the same).

[image]

Please note that filters are not the same columns in the data raw but values are the same. Same for the columns "team".

Can you please help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you show how you expect the graph to look like?

Comment: @P.b thank you for your comment. I added a graph.

Comment: Maybe add a column to the first table to match the values to the team name by vlookup or index match. Add an iferror to it to create blanks and then use this table to get your graph.

Comment: I cannot do this in a pivot ...